# Connection between derivatives in Galois theory and calculus

Tags: calculus, galois-theory, galois-extensions

In field theory, we can define a function
$d:F[X]\to F[X]$ where $\sum_{i=0}^n a_iX^i \mapsto \sum_{i=1}^n ia_iX^{i-1}$, where $F[X]$ is some polynomial ring.

Letting $d(f)=f'$ for $f\in F[X]$, I have recently learned in my Galois theory class that this function is useful in the following way:

1. $f$ has no multiple roots in any extension field $\iff$ GCD$(f,f')=1$.
2. If $f$ irreducible, then we have $f$ separable $\iff$ $f'\neq 0$.

Alternatively, we learn in calculus that we can calculate the derivative of a polynomial to get an equation that gives the slope of the tangent line at any point in the domain.

On the surface, this function feels totally unrelated to slopes or tangent lines, so it feels like a remarkable coincidence that their definitions coincide on polynomials. Is there any reason I should've expected a priori that they are the same? Is there some connection here I am missing? Or is it simply that those working in with these field extensions were aware of the tools of calculus and applied them here?

Thanks in advance for any thoughts on this.

Comment: Well, for polynomials both operators are formally identical. If $D$ is the "calculus" derivative operator and $d$ is your ring homomorphism, then given a polynomial $f$ in $\mathbb{R}[X]$, $Df$ is another polynomial in $\mathbb{R}[X]$ which is the same polynomial as $df$.

Comment: That is because $D$ and $d$ both satisfy linearity and the product rule, and map constants to $0$ and $X$ to $1$. All polynomials are built up from constants, $X$, addition and multiplication, so inductively the operators act the same way on $\mathbb{R}[X]$. To be more precise, $D$ should actually act on the set of functions $\mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ that happen to be defined by a polynomial expression, but you can ignore this and treat them as abstract polynomials.

Comment: @TobErnack Right, that's what I mean when I say that their "definitions coincide on polynomials." My question is why that definition is used for both detecting separability and finding slopes of tangent lines, two things between which I wouldn't anticipate a connection a priori as they seem quite different.

Comment: I think the question is "Why would we expect a-priori that this operator is useful as an operator on polynomials, aside from its interpretation in calculus?" moreso than "prove these operators coincide."

Comment: Ah I misunderstood the question because you seemed surprised that their definitions coincided on polynomials.

Comment: To understand the connection between separability and slopes of tangent lines, note first that a polynomial $f$ has a root at $r$ iff it can be factored as $(X - r)g$ for another polynomial $g$ with $\deg g = \deg f - 1$ (this is an algebraic consequence of $F[X]$ being a euclidean domain with the degree as the valuation). And $f$ has a repeated root $r$ iff it is of the form $(X - r)^2g$. When $f$ is a polynomial over $\mathbb{R}$, you can see that its derivative at $r$ will be zero. And for polynomials, the converse is also true because of the Taylor expansion at $r$.

Comment: (cont') i.e. if $f$ and $f'$ have a common root at $r$ then $r$ is a repeated root for $f$. That holds true in calculus already. So the derivative operator connects repeated roots (the algebraic fact) with the slope of tangent lines (the geometric fact), and it does so purely through these properties of linearity and product-rule, so it can be generalized to settings where slopes of tangent lines are not defined (fields more general than $\mathbb{R}$). Not sure if that comment helps more or not.

Comment: $d$ is not a ring homomorphism unless $F$ is the zero ring.

Comment: @MarkSaving Good point, thank you, corrected to say "function."

Comment: Also, I found this, which is related: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1368186/generalization-of-the-derivative-to-polynomial-rings